# Handling DataBinding errors when switching Git branch

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding

I have a lot of issues with DataBinding when switching between Git branches where a databinding layout has been changed/removed. I regularly get build errors like this when a file is removed when switching Git branch:

```
<path>/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/com/some/package/databinding/SomeLayoutBinding.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    public final SomeOtherLayoutBinding variable;
```

...and try every combination of

- Clean Project
- ./gradlew cleanBuildCache
- Sync project with gradle
- Invalidate/Restart

but ultimately none of it resolves the issue.

The only thing I've found that works is to clear the gradle cache in my home directory like:

`rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches`

however this results in my next build taking up to 10min.

Is it really supposed to be like this? Why can't it detect that a file is added/removed when switching branch?