# how to clean up generated data binding files?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-binding

I've got a problem

I created the activity and xml files in a git branch.

Commit these tasks, and change the branch to do something else.

However, when build app, the following error occurred.

```
/Users/xxxx/Desktop/product/product-app-android/app/build/generated/source/kapt/stgDebug/kr/co/product/product/databinding/ActivityDebugUserInfoBindingImpl.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
```

ActivityDebugUserInfo is the file I created in the previous branch.

**There is no such file in the current branch. Nevertheless, it was created automatically**

I repeated clean project and rebuild, invalid cache and restart. However, the problem was not solved.

The automatically generated file has been revived like a zombie.

Obviously, I think the file will be automatically generated based on some cache data.

But i don't know what it is.

How can i refresh generated databinding file?

Comment: Similar to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340113/handling-databinding-errors-when-switching-git-branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self answer.

In my case, after fixing the following code, the problem was solved.

To speed up the build I used the following code in gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.daemon = true
org.gradle.parallel = true
org.gradle.configureondemond = true
org.gradle.caching = true
```

Because of this, clean did not work properly. After commenting the code, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The same error as you.
Need change `org.gradle.caching = true` to`org.gradle.caching = false`, and then everythis is ok.

But why?  We can't use incremental builds? What's the actual problem?

`org.gradle.caching = true` can dramatically speed up clean and incremental builds.[help provide quick build performance wins](https://goobar.io/understanding-profiling-and-optimizing-gradle-in-android-builds/)

Answer (score 0):

change gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.parallel=false
org.gradle.caching=false
```

sync

clean & build ,worked for me